# PHP CodeSniffer include_once error

Tags: php, macos, phpcodesniffer

I'm trying to install PHP CodeSniffer on OS X Mountain Lion - and I appear to be getting a strange problem

When running 'phpcs' I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php): failed to open stream: No such
file or directory in /usr/lib/php/pear/bin/phpcs on line 31

PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php' for inclusion
(include_path='.;/usr/lib/php/pear/share/pear/') in /usr/lib/php/pear/bin/phpcs on line 31

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI' not found in /usr/lib/php/pear/bin/phpcs
on line 34
```

The file /usr/lib/php/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php exists, which is confusing me

Comment: is `/usr/lib/php/pear/share/pear/` in your PHP default include list? (check php.ini)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - I was using the Windows separator (semi-colon) in the include_path instead of the Unix one (colon), so it should've been:

```
 .:/usr/lib/php/pear/share/pear/
```

instead of

```
 .;/usr/lib/php/pear/share/pear/
```

Comment: IMHO this is a better answer than the others, just set your include path properly.

Answer (score 12):

On my configuration the PHP/ path just wasn't where phpcs expected it.
I solved it via creating symlink to the missing path.

go to pear directory and run:

```
ln -s share/pear/PHP/ PHP
```

Comment: Not quite the one I needed, but got me to a solution. Thx

Comment: My `pear` directory was in my user folder (`~/pear`), so I had to add that to the `include_path` in php.ini.

Answer (score 7):

This is perhaps not the best solution, but it requires no change to your path or anything else.
In the file phpcs you will find a section with:

```
if (is_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php') === true) {
   include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
else {
   include_once 'PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
}
```

Just add a new else if with your path to the correct file CLI.php (i.e. '/usr/local/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php'):

```
if (is_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php') === true) {
   include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
} else if (is_file('/usr/local/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php')) {
   include_once '/usr/local/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
} else {
   include_once 'PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
}
```

Last but not least document this change for later versions and updates.
In the end the solution has to be that the developer of PHPCS makes a more solid construction for finding the CLI.php

Comment: I love this kind of solutions :). Thanks mister, you saved my day .

Answer (score 6):

I got this error when using PHP CodeSniffer installed via [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/).

Fixed it with:

```
cd /path/to/app
rm -rf vendor/
composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MAMP include this in your path:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.X.XX/lib/php:$PATH
```

by replacing 5.X.XX with your php version. In my case this was:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.26/lib/php:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall it and reinstall it using composer

```
alias php=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php;
composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*";
```

Source: https://tommcfarlin.com/php-codesniffer-with-composer/

Answer (score 0):

In my case -- having installed [PHP-OSX](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) -- I had to fix the symlink like so:

```
cd /usr/local/php5/lib/php/PHP
```

and then:

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer
ln -s /usr/local/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer.php
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I installed PHP using homebrew (OS X).  First install was 5.6.3, but upgraded over time.  The default ini file, you can find the location of the file with:

```
php -i | grep ini
```

on osx - still had path references to 5.6.3.  When I updated these - specifically the include path, all worked just fine; no symlinks required.

Answer (score 0):

This `D:\wamp\bin\php\php_VERSION\phpcs` modification worked for me on wamp

```
if (is_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php') === true) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
} else if (is_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php') === true) {
   include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
} else {
    include_once 'PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php';
}

$cli = new PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI();
$cli->runphpcs();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue trying to run phpcs as a non-privileged user, having installed it via PEAR, as root.

Fix for me was to change permissions so that the non-privileged user could access the dependencies:

```
chmod -R o+rx /usr/local/lib/php/
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the correct path to the other directory that PHP scans for INI files (it's listed in phpinfo.php). Execute these three commands from Terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Web/Config/php

sudo touch /Library/Server/Web/Config/php/local.ini

echo 'include_path = ".:'`pear config-get php_dir`'"' | sudo tee -a /Library/Server/Web/Config/php/local.ini
```